# QGIS Online features ArcGIS Online

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online-basemaps, online

Does QGIS online have the ability to publish layers online similar to ArcGIS Online?

Comment: See here (I've no relation with this company) : https://qgiscloud.com/pages/plans?locale=en. Please edit your question to give more context, like : what do you call "QGIS Online" ?

Answer (score 1):

if you open the plugin manager and search for "online" or "webmap" you will find several plugin that let you do that

Some of these plugin are provided by company as a way to easily interact with their online mapping solution (so you will need to create an account, depending on the provider you may get free or paid account).

Other plugin let you publish web map on open source webmapping solution but in this case you will need to set up your own sever.

You may also want to investigate QGIS server